# Plotting more than two columns in python using Panda from a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I am very new to python and coding in general. I have a CSV file that has the first row a string of flight attributes (ie. time, speed, heading, battery voltage etc.) I want to be able to plot time vs speed vs battery voltage. Or battery voltage vs speed. I have tried several examples, however, every example I have seen it is either plots everything in the CSV file which I do not want. Or the csv file only has 2 columns.

```
CSV File format:
time(ms), ground_speed, battery_voltage(v), airspeed(m/s)
1322,45,12,42
1342,64,11,60
1352,30,11,27

import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')


df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('myflight.csv', index_col=False)

df.plot(x='mSec', y='Airspeed(m/s)', color="g")
df.plot(x='mSec', y='AS_Cmd(m/s)', color="r")
```

My issue with this it always plots vs the first index which is time. Also, I get two separate graphs. How do I join both airspeed and AS_Cmd into one graph and be able to plot someone else beside time vs something else?

Comment: In your example can you remove the commas and put one space instead please? Then `pd.read_clipboard()` works correctly. Also the keys you use for plotting do not match the keys in your example data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're new with python you probably should start slower and try to mess around with `numpy` first. `pandas` is a library build around `numpy`, which expects you to be familiar with that.

We can simplify your code a bit. I've added some comments to guide you through.

```
# You do not need that many import statements, so we just import
# numpy and matplotlib using the common alias 'np' and 'plt'.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

# Using numpy we can use the function loadtxt to load your CSV file.
# We ignore the first line with the column names and use ',' as a delimiter.
data = np.loadtxt('myflight.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=1)

# You can access the columns directly, but let us just define them for clarity.
# This uses array slicing/indexing to cut the correct columns into variables.
time = data[:,0]
ground_speed = data[:,1]
voltage = data[:,2]
airspeed = data[:,3]

# With matplotlib we define a new subplot with a certain size (10x10)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))

ax.plot(time, ground_speed, label='Ground speed [m/s]')
ax.plot(time, voltage, label='Voltage [V]')

# Show the legend
plt.legend()
```

This code will get you this graph here:

[image]

### References

You can find the documentation to the functions used in the [NumPy reference](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/index.html).

- [numpy.loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html)
- [Indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

### Update

To clarify on the use of `plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))`: You create a new figure with this command, but matplotlib wants to return several values (two in this case). Therefore you need to specify two variables to accept those. `fig` saves the Figure instance, while `ax` will save the current `subplot`.
A figure can have an unlimited amount of subplots, so you can do fancy things as shown [here](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/intro/matplotlib/matplotlib.html#subplots). In the example above we are only defining one subplot.

The `figsize` attribute defines the size of the Figure in inches, thus the resulting output is 10 x 10 inches. You can play around with the values and look at the outputs.

Comment: could you explain the line fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))?

Comment: I've updated the original answer with some more information!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply set your desired index and plot everything in one shot:

```
import matplotlib

matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

df.set_index('time(ms)')[['ground_speed','battery_voltage(v)']].plot(rot=0, figsize=(16,10))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To directly solve your problem without going deeper just do this:

```
subp = plt.figure().add_subplot(111)
df.plot(x='mSec', y='Airspeed(m/s)', color="g", ax=subp)
df.plot(x='mSec', y='AS_Cmd(m/s)', color="r", ax=subp)
```

You need to define a common object which to plot your plots on and give it to your plot commands, otherwise each time you plot a new one is created.